# How to test UITextView if it's nil in Swift?

Tags: swift, testing, null, uitextview

I m trying to operate a uitextview in GCD, but it sometimes is nil.

when i write the following code, build failed.

```
if myUITextview==nil
{
     ...           
}
```

the error message is:
Binary operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'UITextView' and 'nil'

Any one knows the reason will be appreciated. thanks a lot...

Comment: Your text view is not optional, so it cannot be nil.

Comment: so how to test if the uitextview is empty?